# how to make wall for snake game in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, terminal, console

I made a snake game but now i want to add feature on terminal that player can choose the game mode bound mode (wall) and unbound mode (no wall). I want to know how can i make the wall as i have seen some projects using symbols such as "#" and when the snake head hits the wall the player loses the game.

```
'        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            byte right = 0;
            byte left = 1;
            byte down = 2;
            byte up = 3;
            int currentTime = Environment.TickCount;
            int lastFoodTime = 0;
            int foodDissapearTime = 10000; //food dissappears after 10 second 
            int negativePoints = 0;
            Position[] directions = new Position[4];

            Program p = new Program();
            //display start screen before background music and game start 
            p.DisplayStartScreen();
            //Play background music
            p.BackgroundMusic();

            // Define direction with characteristic of index of array
            p.Direction(directions);

            // Initialised the obstacles location at the starting of the game
            List<Position> obstacles = new List<Position>();
            p.InitialRandomObstacles(obstacles);

            //Do the initialization for sleepTime (Game's Speed), Snake's direction and food timing
            //Limit the number of rows of text accessible in the console window
            double sleepTime = 100;
            int direction = right;
            Random randomNumbersGenerator = new Random();
            Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight;
            lastFoodTime = Environment.TickCount;

            //Initialise the snake position in top left corner of the windows
            //Havent draw the snake elements in the windows yet. Will be drawn in the code below
            Queue<Position> snakeElements = new Queue<Position>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) // Length of the snake was reduced to 3 units of *
            {
                snakeElements.Enqueue(new Position(0, i));
            }

            //To position food randomly when the program runs first time
            Position food = new Position();
            p.GenerateFood(ref food,snakeElements,obstacles);

            //while the game is running position snake on terminal with shape "*"
            foreach (Position position in snakeElements)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(position.col, position.row);
                p.DrawSnakeBody();
            }

            while (true)
            {
                //negative points is initialized as 0 at the beginning of the game. As the player reaches out for food
                //negative points increment depending how far the food is
                negativePoints++;

                //Check the user input direction
                p.CheckUserInput(ref direction, right, left, down, up);

                //When the game starts the snake head is towards the end of his body with face direct to start from right.
                Position snakeHead = snakeElements.Last();
                Position nextDirection = directions[direction];

                //Snake position to go within the terminal window assigned.
                Position snakeNewHead = new Position(snakeHead.row + nextDirection.row,
                    snakeHead.col + nextDirection.col);

                if (snakeNewHead.col < 0) snakeNewHead.col = Console.WindowWidth - 1;
                if (snakeNewHead.row < 0) snakeNewHead.row = Console.WindowHeight - 1;
                if (snakeNewHead.row >= Console.WindowHeight) snakeNewHead.row = 0;
                if (snakeNewHead.col >= Console.WindowWidth) snakeNewHead.col = 0;

                //Check for GameOver Criteria
                int gameOver=p.GameOverCheck(currentTime, snakeElements, snakeNewHead, negativePoints,obstacles);
                if (gameOver == 1)
                    return;

                //Check for Winning Criteria
                int winning = p.WinningCheck(snakeElements, negativePoints);
                if (winning == 1) return;

                //The way snake head will change as the player changes his direction
                Console.SetCursorPosition(snakeHead.col, snakeHead.row);
                p.DrawSnakeBody();

                //Snake head shape when the user presses the key to change his direction
                snakeElements.Enqueue(snakeNewHead);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(snakeNewHead.col, snakeNewHead.row);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                if (direction == right) Console.Write(">"); //Snake head when going right
                if (direction == left) Console.Write("<");//Snake head when going left
                if (direction == up) Console.Write("^");//Snake head when going up
                if (direction == down) Console.Write("v");//Snake head when going down


                // food will be positioned randomly until they are not at the same row & column as snake head
                if (snakeNewHead.col == food.col && snakeNewHead.row == food.row)
                {
                    Console.Beep();// Make a sound effect when food was eaten.
                    p.GenerateFood(ref food, snakeElements, obstacles);


                    //when the snake eat the food, the system tickcount will be set as lastFoodTime
                    //new food will be drawn, snake speed will increases
                    lastFoodTime = Environment.TickCount;
                    sleepTime--;

                    //Generate new obstacle
                    p.GenerateNewObstacle(ref food,snakeElements,obstacles);

                }
                else
                {
                    // snake is moving
                    Position last = snakeElements.Dequeue();
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(last.col, last.row);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }

                //if snake did not eat the food before it disappears, 50 will be added to negative points
                //draw new food after the previous one disappeared
                if (Environment.TickCount - lastFoodTime >= foodDissapearTime)
                {
                    negativePoints = negativePoints + 50;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(food.col, food.row);
                    Console.Write(" ");

                    //Generate the new food and record the system tick count
                    p.GenerateFood(ref food, snakeElements, obstacles);
                    lastFoodTime = Environment.TickCount;
                }

                //snake moving speed increased 
                sleepTime -= 0.01;

                //pause the execution thread of snake moving speed
                Thread.Sleep((int)sleepTime);
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Hi Abdullah! Looks like you've got all the elements you might need around obstacles and collision detection with the snake body, checking the window size, drawing the snake, etc.. What happens if you add behavior to build another object to act as a wall in a similar fashion before the game starts and use your collision detection checks? If you try something and run into issues, you can update your question to share what you've attempted and will be better positioned for help.

Comment: yeh the collision detection checks can be used but i am not quite sure how to make the wall with any symbol. I have looked into other projects online but i am confused. Can you guide me how to print a wall. Thank you @AdamG

Answer (score 0):

Your code has all the pieces it needs; you're building out your game's state before the main loop starts, then you're checking for user input, performing collision detection, checking for game-ending scenarios, drawing the updates to the snake body at specific positions on screen, etc.

The behavior for a wall and its collision checks are not that much different then the behavior for the snake body, but setting up the wall is something you want to do before the main game loop and it's something that's not going to need to be enqueued/dequeued like the snake body positions.

What if you add some setup code before your main game loop starts to create a `List` of `Position` to store the walls and then generate a `for` loop to try adding the Positions of the wall to the list and drawing them to the console based on the size of the console window? You know the `x` and `y` constraints of the console, as you're already using them in the check for the position of the snake head; during your main game loop, you can check for collisions against the wall position list just like you do the snake body position list, and have your game behave accordingly.

Breaking the problem up into discrete steps is probably a good start.

1. How do I draw a rectangle on the console?
2. How do I draw that rectangle before my game starts?
3. How do I make the rectangle fill the space I want it to?
4. How do I track where I drew the rectangle so I can check if the snake hits it?
5. How do I check if the snake hits one of the wall positions during the main game loop?

Comment: Thank you. So what i understand is that the first step i need to do use loop to generate a wall. Once i am able to do that then, i can use the collision function accordingly.

Comment: can i use something like this, using the Map class and then calling it in the main? https://2god.tistory.com/68

Comment: I added some discrete steps that might help thinking about how to tackle the problem. Take it one step at a time and don't worry about getting to "functional wall" in one go; you might find other cool uses for what you discover, like adding backgrounds or different obstacle types.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I will follow the steps to achieve the required goal.